# style change and setTimeout issues

Tags: javascript, css, settimeout, reload

I want to move an element slowly across the screen by changing the style.left value and using settimeout() to control the change interval.

To start the sequence I was using a settimeout to the function in body onload.

then at end of function doing a delayed recall of same function to continue the sequence.

The problem appears to be that the style.left value change causes a reload which causes the onload timer to fire again. The element flashes across the screen to its final position as soon as you open page even tho timeout delay is 5 seconds. ??

I am aware of the newer css animation techniques, but they do not fit my need.

is the above paragraph a correct assumption??

Comment: Can you post your JS?

Comment: Maybe you should try `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: Yeah, a `setTimeout` shouldn't cause a reload. There's some other code that's messing up on you. Please provide a jsfiddle.

Comment: Your issue could be related to the "delayed recall" have you tried it without to see if the initial animation works.  If it does, then as @zgood has already said setInterval is probably what you are looking for instead. As others have said, code is our friend here.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest issue here is that you are using SetTimeout instead of SetInterval. You could easily accomplish this with SetInterval. I am including a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/33n99haj/1/

```
<div id="box" style="width:30px;height:30px;background-color:red;position:absolute;"></div>

window.e = document.getElementById("box");
var i = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    i = i + 20;
    window.e.style.left = i + "px";;
},1000);
```

Don't forget that your position should be absolute in your CSS